# couchDB unable to create a database with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I am new to node.js (just few days in) and am learning through a tutorial from youtube (don't know if it's allowed to post a link or not).

I am trying to create a database in couchDB. Everything works fine but as soon as I try to enter any details on the form, it displays the exception "Error creating Database Address" (Address is the name of the database I am trying to create)

I followed the tutorial very carefully and have been searching for a solution for a while now but end up with nothing.

Please help if you found something.

[image: Here is the image of the local host]

[image: Here is the image of the error]

**App.js:**

```js
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var urlencoded = require('url');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var json = require('json');
var logger = require('logger');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var nano = require('nano')('http://admin:password@localhost:5984');

var db = nano.use('address');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/',routes.index);

app.post('/createdb', function(req, res) {
    nano.db.create(req.body.dbname, function(err){
        if(err) {
            res.send("Error creating Database " + req.body.dbname);
            return;
        }

        res.send("Database " + req.body.dbname + "created successfully");
    });
});

app.post('/new_contact', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var phone = req.body.phone;

    db.insert({name : name, phone : phone, crazy : true}, phone, function(err,body, header) {
        if(err) {
            res.send("Error creating contact");
            return;
        }
        res.send("Contact created successfully");
    });
});


app.post('/view_contact', function(req, res) {
    var alldoc = "Following are the contacts";
    db.get(req.body.phone, {revs_info : true}, function(err, body) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log(body);
        }
        if(body) {
            alldoc += "Name: " + body.name + "<br/>Phone Number: " + body.phone;
        }
        else {
            alldoc = "No records found";
        }
        res.send(alldoc);
    });
});


app.post('/delete_contact', function(req, res) {
    db.get(req.body.phone, {revs_info : true}, function(err, body) {
        if(!err) {
            db.destroy(req.body.phone, body._rev, function(err, body) {
                if(err) {
                    res.send("error deleting contact");
                }
            });
            res.send("Contacts deleted successfullly");
        }
    });
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port: ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**index.js**

```js
exports.index = function(req,res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'express'});
};
```

**createdb.js**

```js
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    nano.db.create(req.body.dbname, function() {
        if(err) {
            res.send("Error creating the Database");
            return;
        }
        res.send("database created successfully");
    });
};
```

index.js and createdb.js both are in routes folder

**index.jade**

```jade
extend layout 

block content 
    h1 Add new Contact 
    form(method="POST", action = '/new_contact')
        p name:
        input#title(type = "text", name = "name")
        p Phone No.: 
        input#title(type = "text", name = "phone")

        p: button(type = "submit") Add new Contact 

    h1 Add new Database 
    form(method = "POST", action= "/createdb")
        p Database name: 
        input#title(type = "text", name = "dbname")
        
        p: button(type="submit") Add new Database

    h1 enter Phone number to delete new_contact
    form(method = "POST", action= "/delete_contact")
        p Phone No.: 
        input#title(type = "text", name = "phone")
        
        p: button(type="submit") Delete Contact 

    h1 View Specific contact
    form(method = "POST", action= "/view_contact")
        p Phone No.: 
        input#title(type = "text", name = "phone")
        
        p: button(type="submit") Search Contact
```

**layout.jade**

```js
doctype html
html
    head
        title = title 
        //- link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheet/style.css')
    body 
        block content
```

**layout.jade** and **index.jade** are present in views folder

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "just a sample.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "json": "^10.0.0",
    "logger": "0.0.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "nano": "^9.0.3",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed jade to Pug, still the same issue.

Comment: Please don't post images, over time they end up as broken links, and more importantly it prevents those with visual impairments from helping.

Comment: I added a link, someone edited it, please guide me to some another way so I can describe my problem without effecting anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just briefly skimming over the code, it looks like you're not passing any authentication details to nano:

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984');
var db = nano.use('address');

/* ... */

app.post('/createdb', function(req, res) {
    nano.db.create(req.body.dbname, function(err){
```

This might have worked in old versions of CouchDB running in admin party mode, which is not supported anymore from CouchDB 3.0 onwards.

When installing CouchDB locally, you'll need to setup a admin user and password before getting started.

When using nano, you need to provide the credentials like:

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://admin:password@localhost:5984')
```

Comment: Same issue, didn't work, var nano = require('nano')('http://admin:password@localhost:5984'); [password is password only, so it should work right?] edited the post too with the same. @LyteFM

Comment: Well, the credentials need to be correct and CouchDB needs to be running. Can you log into Fauxton via the Browser at http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/# ? Does it work if you just run a minimal example via nodejs like: `var nano = require('nano'('http://admin:password@localhost:5984'); 
nano.db.create('test')`?

Comment: Yes that works. test DB is created. But can't figure out what the error is coming then which results in the execution of else statement.

Comment: Actually you know what, I am kind of an idiot. Only lowercase letters are allowed in DB name, I was adding Address(first letter is capital). Console logged the err and fixed it, now its working fine.